# Denormalizing using query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, crosstab

I've a table like this:

```
STU_NAME  SUBJECT   MARKS
--------- --------- ------
1         ENGLISH   90
1         TAMIL     80 
1         MATHS     70 
2         MATHS     70
2         TAMIL     80
2         ENGLISH   95
```

And the result should be like below:

```
STU_NAME  MATHS_MARK  ENGLISH_MARK TAMIL_MARK  TOTAL_MARKS
--------- ----------- ------------ ----------- -------------
1            70            90            80            240
2            70            95            80            245
```

Can we achieve this with a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that the easiest way is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select stu_name,
       max(case when subject = 'MATHS' then Marks end) as Maths,
       max(case when subject = 'ENGLISH' then Marks end) as English,
       max(case when subject = 'TAMIL' then Marks end) as Tamil,
       sum(Marks) as Total
from t
group by stu_name;
```

Comment: Great!., Cud U just tel me how it's picking the respective subject marks.,?

Comment: @Vicky, you forgot the magic words like `please`or `Thank you`

Comment: Ho! Thank you very much.:)

Comment: @gordon-linoff It works well on `t-sql` as well. One minor drawback is you have to change the possible null by converting them to varchar then use the equivalent of an `isnull` . Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same using PIVOT function.,

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   x)
PIVOT  (MAX(marks)  FOR (SUBJECT) IN ('ENGLISH', 'MATHS', 'TAMIL'));
```

But, Still I'm facing few issues.,

1. whether it is possible to get sum(marks) while using PIVOT.
2. And getting subjects with respective marks without mentioning every subject(when we do know what are the subjects will be) in both(case,pivot).,?

Comment: If you want `sum(marks)`, then use conditional aggregation (although you can also do it using `pivot`).